# Редактирование двумерного динамического массива

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Здравствуйте! Есть динамический массив

`char **le=new char*[31]`

И есть статический массив `char buf[200]={}`, в котором находятся строки, разделённые символом '#'(то ест вот так "sfgv#gbchj#grsf#"), в конце этот символ. Мне нужно из этого массива `buf` эти данные вставить по-порядку в динамический массив `le`, то есть

`le[0]="sfgv";le[1]="gbchj"` и т.д.

Я делаю это так, но программа вылетает

```
for(int i(0),b(0),c(0);i<strlen(buf);i++)
if(buf[i]=='#')
{
b=0; c++;
}
else
{
le[c][b]=buf[i]; //вылетает
b++;
}
```

Comment: Вы не выделили память для хранения строк. Вы лишь выделили память для указателей на строки.

Comment: То есть нужно ещё le[i]=new char...?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Я так понимаю, что человеку нужно вставить в массив указателей указатели на части этой строки?

Comment: @АртурКлочко Если вы хотите копировать подстроки из исходного массива в другой массив, то вам надо выделить память для этих подстрок, куда они будут записаны. Вы же выделили память лишь для указателей на строки.

Comment: @АртурКлочко Офтоп. Скажите, мне интересно, откуда вы взяли понятие "динамический массив", из книги, преподаватель сказал или еще откуда-нибудь?

Comment: @Cerbo, та на сайте, cppstudio вроде. А что?

Comment: @АртурКлочко Просто не первый раз это вижу и все думаю откуда это берется.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы делал так:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char buf[] = "dfsfs#fjghdfgf#gfdghfdghD#gfdfgdghfd#gfdgfdgfd#gfdgfdgf#gdfgd";
    char **le = new char*[31];

    int N = 0;
    le[N++] = buf;
    for(char * c = buf; *c; ++c)
    {
        if (*c == '#')
        {
            *c = 0;
            if (*(++c)) le[N++] = c;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        cout << le[i] << endl;
}
```

Здесь содержимое `buf` **не** копируется; в `le` просто сохраняются указатели на куски строк в `buf` - т.е. `le` корректен, пока существует `buf`. При этом символы `#` в `buf` заменены на нулевые (`buf` порезан на отдельные строки).